# Unable to generate g.dart with retrofit flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, serialization, retrofit, generator

I am migrating my flutter project to `3.3.0` and i am calling API with `retrofit` which was working fine, after upgrading all packages i delete .g.dart file and run the following command to rebuild the .g.dart file

`flutter pub run build_runner build` it thrown the following error.

```
    Error: No named parameter with the name 'autoCastResponse'.
      autoCastResponse: annotation?.peek('autoCastResponse')?.boolValue,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/ahmad/Android/Android%20Bundle%20Setup/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/retrofit-3.3.0/lib/http.dart:66:9: Context: Found this candidate, but th
e arguments don't match.
  const RestApi({
        ^^^^^^^
/E:/ahmad/Android/Android%20Bundle%20Setup/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/retrofit_generator-4.1.2/lib/src/generator.dart:494:27: Error: The getter 'autoCastResponse' isn't defined for the class 'RestApi'.
 - 'RestApi' is from 'package:retrofit/http.dart' ('/E:/ahmad/Android/Android%20Bundle%20Setup/flutter/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/retrofit-3.3.0/lib/http.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'autoCastResponse'.
        (clientAnnotation.autoCastResponse ?? true);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 900ms
[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
pub finished with exit code 78
```

I also try this command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` 
But the result remains the same.

Here is how my abstract class looks like,

```
part 'rest_client.g.dart';
@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://myapi.com/")
abstract class RestClient {
   factory RestClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _RestClient;

  @POST("/Flag")
  Future<LoginResponse> login(@Body() LoginRequest loginRequest)`;}`
```

These are my packages version:

```
retrofit: ^3.3.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  retrofit_generator: ^4.1.2
  build_runner: ^2.2.1
  json_serializable: ^6.4.1

  dependency_overrides:
    analyzer: '5.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [githubLink](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/511)

`retrofit: 3.3.0` had bugs and the author forgot to publish the generator accordingly. So after resolving that bug using `retrofit: ^3.3.1` and `retrofit_generator: 4.2.0` is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade the package retrofit_generator to 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

you need to take care of the file naming your file name should be like what you will generate if you will generate [users.g.dart] your file name should be [ users.dart] or it will not create the file
and also upgrade your package to retrofit_generator: ^4.0.3+1